# Customer selects type of configurable product > Query for vendors with that product

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, sql, configurable-product

I would like some advice on how to go about this project before I start! We are developing a Magento site where other vendors can sell their product.

My first project:

> "Get product structure to display correctly on product pages.  There
>   is an attribute called “vendor”.  There is a “Tier 2” Simple product
>   created “for” every configurable but is not “included” in the
>   configuration.  This “Tier 2” product has a vendor ID of “0”.  This is
>   for display only in the vendors login system.  So what we will have
>   will look like:
>
> 1)      Configurable SKU             1001
>
> 2)      “Tier 2” SKU’s                    1001-blu | 1001-wht |
>   1001-blk | 1001-red
>
> 3)      Simple Product SKU’s    1001-blu-ven1 | 1001-blu-ven3 |
>   1001-wht-ven3 | 1001-blk-ven1 |1001-blk-ven2 | 1001-blk-ven3
>   |1001-red-ven1 | 1001-red-ven2 | 1001-red-ven3
>
> So, with that said, you will have 9 SKU’s under 1001 Configurable. 
>   The challenge is to write the page so that it displays all
>   configurations – Red, Blue White and Black PRIOR to displaying the
>   “show vendors” button.  Once all required configurations have been
>   chosen, the “show vendors” button will display.  Once clicked, a
>   display (It has yet to be undecided if it will be a jQuery
>   .slidedown() or a jQuery popup)  will display the vendors (think
>   “attribute”) and prices for said configuration. "

I'm thinking to set up some test products, just assuming that one vendor or another will carry each. Then when user selects specific color- search database for vendor attribute. **What I really need advice on is what tables to set up if any and/or how to query for the results.** Any help VERY much appreciated! :D

Comment: Nevermind, I was being silly. You can apply the vendor attribute to the simple products only and then if a red product is generated for vendor1, for example, then when red is selected, vendor1 will show up as an option by default. My work is going to be more in the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I was being silly. You can apply the vendor attribute to the simple products only and then if a red product is generated for vendor1, for example, then when red is selected, vendor1 will show up as an option by default. My work is going to be more in the display.